# RadioGroup implementation in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following `xml` and `ViewModel` source code. I am working on the `radiogroup` where I have two radiobuttons (Male and Female). Initially, I want `Male` radio button to be selected(default). However, my current implementation does not show any of radio button being selected. Both of them are shown as not selected.I am using MvvmCross version 4.0

**xml**

```
<mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.appcompat.widget.MvxAppCompatRadioGroup
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_radio"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;ItemSelected SelectedItem" />
```

**Item_radio.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="12sp"
  local:MvxBind="Text Caption" />
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
private List<Thing> _items = new List<Thing>()
{
   new Thing("Male"),
   new Thing("Female"),
};

public List<Thing> Items
{
  get { return _items; }
  set { _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items); }
}

private Thing _selectedItem = new Thing("Male");
public Thing SelectedItem
{
  get 
  {
    return _selectedItem; 
  }
  set
  {
     _selectedItem = value;
     RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
  }
}
```

In the **Setup.cs**

```
 registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<MvxAppCompatRadioGroup>("ItemSelected", view => new MyRadioItemSelectedBinding(view)));
```

Comment: what does your "item_radio" layout template look like?

Comment: I have added, please check update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be you were binding to `ItemSelected` instead of `SelectedItem`.

Your xml layout control should be:

```
<mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.appcompat.widget.MvxAppCompatRadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_radio"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; SelectedItem SelectedItem" />
```

Comment: Please check my Setup.cs , just added in the question.

Comment: @hotspring, what does `MyRadioItemSelectedBinding` look like? Is there a specific reason why you need to use a custom binding over the already included SelectedItem?

Comment: I have just used `SelectedItem` and it has worked! I have updated MvvmCross 4.0 to 4.2.1 and used `SelectedItem`

Comment: @hotspring, awesome

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r I am using `SelectedItem SelectedItem` but still any of my radio button show selected.

Comment: @NickKing do you have a code snippet or sample I can checkout?

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r you can take a look at this : [link](https://gist.github.com/kaj5/fe733ec21e8eaa331c8a218f80e02e0c)